# "Premature end of file" while parsing xml from the net

Tags: java, xml-parsing, sax

When I try to parse XML file from the net in this way:

```
URL url = new URL("http://www.nbp.pl/kursy/xml/a074z120416.xml");
URLConnection uc = url.openConnection();
saxParser.parse(uc.getInputStream(), handler);
```

Premature end of file Exception is throwing.

Stack trace:

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Premature end of file.
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLScanner.reportFatalError(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at com.pmajcher.xmltest.ReadXMLFile.main(ReadXMLFile.java:142)
```

But when I first save that xml to local file, and then try to parse it, everything is ok.

```
URL url = new URL("http://www.nbp.pl/kursy/xml/a074z120416.xml");
URLConnection uc = url.openConnection();
InputStreamReader input = new InputStreamReader(uc.getInputStream());
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(input);
File file = new File("temp.xml");

if(!file.exists()){
    file.createNewFile();
}

PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(file);
String inputLine;

while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
    out.print(inputLine);
}
out.close();
saxParser.parse("temp.xml", handler);
```

What's wrong with the way I try to parse xml from the net?

Comment: Found duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5281746/what-is-difference-between-a-stream-and-the-actual-data

Comment: your copy code is not equivalent.  you are converting the xml bytes to text which could potentially be changing the data.  in order to do a straight comparison, download the xml file as bytes and write to the tmep file as bytes (e.g. InputStream and OutputStream only, no Readers or Writers).

Comment: your first code works fine for me, no sax parse exceptions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code written in the question works well

```
URL url = new URL("http://www.nbp.pl/kursy/xml/a074z120416.xml");
URLConnection uc = url.openConnection();
saxParser.parse(uc.getInputStream(), handler);
```

I can't see any problem here. Maybe when you try it the first time the file was changing, and was not complete.

But now I can confirm you that it works. I try it.

Comment: You are right. This code run for me too. Sorry for my distraction.